# Multi-page App on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, multipage

I am new to iOS development and there is an application that I have been trying to build. But I am stuck on an idea that I want to implement.

The idea is to implement a multi-page app, but not exactly like a book. If you look at the Epicurious App, and if you search for any ingredient, the search results appear in a multi-page format. At the bottom, it shows the search result number (e.g. 5 of 77), and when the user swipes from right to left, the next result appears.

Can someone tell me what type of application (whether a page-based app or utility app) can allow me to that and how to implement multiple pages as described above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template which demonstrates this functionality is the Page-Based App, but you'll need to add some custom code for your search-results requirement.

You're best off starting with a Blank or Single-View Application, then add your search controls and a UIPageViewController.

There's a good tutorial on [techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application) which should get you started.